# Difference between form.show and form.Activate

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to know the difference between `form.show()` and `form.activate()`.

I have multiple forms that already opened and i would like to active my form that is behind another form which is the best way to call my desired form
`form.show()` or `form.activate()`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is was easily searchable and only relied on looking at the documentation

Comment: This doesn't deserve all the down votes. The documentation for Activate and Show don't make it completely clear. Is "bringing to the front" different from "displaying"? TopMost documentation doesn't even call out Activate, nor is it an obvious place to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `Show()` displays the form to the user.

The method `Activate()`  brings the form to the front (it gives the form focus).

For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
        this.Activate();
    }
}
```

The above code will show form2 by calling `form2.Show();` but form1 will be in front of form2 (in focus) because of the `this.Activate();` call.

See MSDN documentation:

- [Show()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Activate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**From the documentation**

[Form.Activate Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Activating a form brings it to the front if this is the active
>   application**, or **it flashes the window caption if this is not the
>   active application**. The form must be visible for this method to have
>   any effect. To determine the active form in an application, use the
>   ActiveForm property or the ActiveMdiChild property if your forms are
>   in a Multiple-document interface (MDI) application.

[Form.Show Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Showing the control is equivalent to setting the Visible property to
>   true. After the Show method is called, the Visible property returns a
>   value of true until the Hide method is called.

---

**Answer**

> I have multiple forms that already opened and i would like to active
>   my form that is behind another form which is the best way to call my
>   desired form form.show() or form.activate()?

If your form is already open `Activate` it probably the one you want

**Tip** : If you ever wonder what a .net method does, just go and type it into google, usually the help is the first thing that shows up, plus a myriad of other questions and answers

Comment: @JeremyThompson yes you would, this is how we learnt how to program

Comment: plus one, I didn't even have the internet learning to code... I had to read an encyclopedia set the size of telephone books on programming.

Comment: @JeremyThompson hahah yeah, google was the back of the book, and straight to the index

Answer (score 1):

As per msdn [Form.Activate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx) &
[Form.Show()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx)

Activate() :-

> Activating a form brings it to the front if this is the active application, or it flashes the window caption if this is not the active application. The form must be visible for this method to have any effect.

Show() :-

> You can use this method to display a non-modal form. When you use this method, the Owner property of the form is set to owner. The non-modal form can use the Owner property to get information about the owning form. Calling this method is identical to setting the Owner property of the non-modal and then calling the Show() method.
>
> Showing the form is equivalent to setting the Visible property to true. After the Show method is called, the Visible property returns a value of true until the Hide method is called.

you can visit above links for more information

Now if you make your purpose more clear we may help in you in "Specific Way"

After reading the edit "Activate" is best , and also my answer is exactly identical to @TheGeneral

Answer (score 1):

`form.activate()` activates the form, which means if you have input elements (such as text boxes), it will focus to that particular form regardless of any other form out there. Eg. If you have shown form 1,2 and 3. And if you activate form 2, the form 2 will get focused to the user.

If you use `form.show()` it will just display/show the form to the user. Thus the `activate()` is gets the highest priority in terms of user engagement.

Answer (score 0):

`Form.Show()` creates a new example of a form, while `Form.Activate()` brings an already existing form in the foreground.